# Can a religious baker refuse service to an underage couple-to-be, in accordance with his deeply-held religious beliefs?

Tags: united-states, discrimination, religion, colorado, customer-service

[As previously asked](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/44004/refusing-service-based-on-sexual-orientation), bakers in certain US states can legally refuse service on the basis of sexual orientation. For the purposes of this question, assume that the state is **Colorado**.

[Child marriage is legal in 48 states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_marriage_in_the_United_States) (all except New Jersey and Delaware) - in 48 states, minors under 18 can marry with parental consent, even in the absence of their own consent, and irrespective of the age of their spouse-to-be.

As an example, I am not a baker, but I personally belong to a religion in which you generally need to be 21 to marry, and our leadership won't even consider it unless both partners are at least 18. Marriage before 21, and definitely before 18, is fundamentally against my deeply-held religious beliefs.

Now let's suppose that I own a bakery. A couple comes in to my bakery to order a custom wedding cake, similar to the Masterpiece situation. One or both members of the couple are under the age of 18. **Can I call on my religious freedom to refuse service to this couple?**

Comment: Just to be clear, the specific service in Masterpiece Cakeshop was the *decoration* of the cake, which would have required the baker to "speak" (in the form of cake decorations) a point of view which they disagreed with. If the gay couple had merely wished to purchase an undecorated or generically decorated cake then the 1st Amendment issue would not have existed.

Comment: Krishna this doesn't seem to be a case of "refusing service to the couple" because **you'd also refuse to let the bride's mother place the order**, correct?  The issue is what is being ordered (a cake celebrating child marriage) and not who places the order.

Comment: You said that minors can marry "even in the absence of their own consent".  What US state allows marriage in the absence of consent of one of the persons being married?

Comment: In accordance with @RossRidge 's comment, is it possible you mixed up [age of consent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_consent) with consenting to be married?

Comment: @Kirshna: just to make it clear: "age of consent" is the age at which a person is deemed to be legally competent to consent to **sexual acts**. This has little to do with "consent to marry another person", although if you agree to marry another person "sexual acts" are an implied part of marriage.

Comment: There is no confusion. Child marriage is legal in 48 states, meaning that in 48 states, a child can be married with the consent of his/her parent/guardian alone, irrespective of his/her own consent. This has nothing to do with age of sexual consent, though I'm not surprised people here are trying to obfuscate the issue.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point, that's correct. I would refuse to let the bride's mother place the order because it is for a child marriage.

Comment: @RossRidge The 48 states linked in the OP allow marriage of minors with parental consent. The child cannot consent, so their will is irrelevant, legally speaking.

Comment: @cat40 No, the article I linked in the OP is about age of marriage, not age of consent. There has been no mix up.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I understand the difference between age of consent and age of marriage. The article I linked in the OP is about age of marriage, not age of consent, and my question is about age of marriage, not age of consent, so please take the question as written. I don't understand why the comments here seem to be changing the subject to age of consent when the question (and the link provided in the question itself) are clearly about age of marriage.

Comment: What if *their* religion says it's OK - perhaps even REQUIRED - but they HAVE to have a cake - and you're the only baker in town. Now you're discriminating against their religion.

Comment: @Krishna Just because the parent needs to consent to the marriage doesn't mean that the child doesn't also need to consent.  The Wikipedia article you linked does not support your assertion that a child's willingness to get married is legally irrelevant.

Comment: @Krishna: Since you now recognize it is a question of electing not to perform a particular type of service no matter who the customer is, and not discrimination against a particular customer, the question needs a complete rewrite.  Actually because there are already answers, you really need to abandon this one and ask a new one.  It probably would help if you fill in a matrix with one dimension being what product (wedding cake vs birthday cake) and another axis being who the customer is (bride vs bride's mother) to clearly illustrate that the issue is not the age of the customer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think the question is fine as-is, since the OP explicitly refers to a similar case as the motivation for the question, and the two issues are obviously intertwined. If answerers think that the distinction is relevant to the answer, they should include that information in their answers.

Comment: You're not the one getting married. Make the dang cake. I guarantee that nothing in your religious text says you cannot make a cake, for someone else, as a job, that has some particular scribblings on it.

Comment: @RossRidge: it appears that the questioner is asserting, as a matter of their own religious belief, that a child by definition cannot consent to marriage, and that in those 48 states the parent's consent therefore must *substitute* for that of the child. Of course this is not the law in the US, which asserts that under suitable circumstances a minor can consent to marriage (and indeed to many other things which legally require consent).

Comment: So, "even in the absence of their own consent" is not a statement of US law, it is a statement of part of the religious belief the questioner is asking about.

Comment: @SteveJessop those states that do allow minors to marry generally require a court to approve so the judge can ensure that there's no coercion.  But judges are neither infallible nor universally ethical, and there seems to be no actual requirement in the law for the minor to consent.

Comment: @ruakh: Being related to another case which is also described wrongly is no excuse for failing to correct the description.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I note that your proposed fix, "abandon this [question] and ask a new one", *also* doesn't involve "correct[ing] the description" here. So your demands aren't entirely consistent. More broadly . . . it's very common on Stack Exchange sites that answerers understand the subject matter better than askers. This means that answers often have to clarify misconceptions in questions. You know this, and you're usually fine with it. Why is it bothering you so much this time?

Comment: @ruakh: Of course "ask a new question with the facts correct" should also involve an edit here, with a summary of why the original presentation is wrong and a link to the new question.  And while it may be common on StackExchange at large to answer the question the asker should have stated, that appears not to be taking place on Law.SE, probably because the question does also have answers as asked even if the situation is unlikely to ever occur (because it is inconsistent with all the major political and religious views).

Comment: @BenVoigt: I suspect that the reason that answerers haven't picked up on your distinction is that it isn't as important and relevant, from a legal standpoint, as you assume. (Presumably "I wouldn't bake a cake for that couple no matter *who* asked me to!" and "I wouldn't bake a cake for that couple no matter *who* they wanted it for!" can trigger the same sorts of discrimination laws.)

Comment: @ruakh: You're missummarizing, though.  The actual stance, as far as I can see, is "I wouldn't bake a cake with that decoration".  "for that couple" is not even under consideration.  It could be "for the purpose of throwing in the trash in front of a million Youtube viewers" and the baker would still refuse to make "that (decorated) cake"

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm not sure why you suggest that. The objection to baking a wedding cake for two men, or two twenty-year-olds, relates to the wedding that it's for, not to any physical property of the cake. (Are you really claiming to believe that a wedding cake for two twenty-year-olds will be decorated differently than one for two twenty-one-year-olds?)

Answer (score 14):

As cited by @xuhdev, discrimination on the basis of **marital status** is prohibited in Colorado. And, even though *age* is not on the list, the couple could claim that you discriminate them based on *their* marital status, whether current or would-be, and whether related to their age or not.

Note that the reason why you discriminate is irrelevant: whether you do it by calling on your religious freedom or without giving any reasons at all does not make any difference. Holding religious beliefs is by no means a lawful excuse for discrimination, no matter how deeply they are held.

Comment: I assume that the baker in question would be absolutely fine selling them two birthday cakes, so the refusal isn't due to age. Of course the baker could say "I'm not selling to people under 18, not ever", so if that is the truth, it would be legal discrimination.

Comment: @gnasher729 Correct, I'd be glad to sell birthday cakes to minors, it's the marriage that's the issue, just like masterpiece.

Comment: How about the baker says "I'm not selling wedding cakes to people under 18, not ever"?

Comment: @xuhdev _"the couple could claim.."_ is the answer. Then it depends on the court.

Comment: @Greendrake I agree. That's what exactly I wanted to say because the comments seem to think otherwise.

Comment: @xuhdev I agree with Greendrake but in this case it would be much simpler for them to simply send an adult to order the cake for them.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem correct, because the discrimination is explicitly based on age, not marital status. Of course the young couple could file a lawsuit, but they could also file a lawsuit for any number of frivolous things that would ultimately be thrown out, so "the couple could claim" isn't an answer to whether or not such discrimination is legal.

Comment: @zaen I remember a rather old court case in the UK before discrimination against gay people was illegal. The jeaulous wife of a male business owner forced the husband to fire his male gay secretary because she feared an affair could happen. First court ruled that discrimination against gay people was (at the time) not illegal. Higher court ruled that the secretary was fired for being male, since a gay female secretary would not start an affair with her male boss. So age is quite possibly _not_ the final reason. It's a case that a judge will enjoy.

Comment: @zaen the point of this answer is that such a claim would be arguable, not frivolous. I think the angle that the discrimination is, at least to some sensible extent, based on marital status makes sense to most people here, so odds are good it would make sense to the judge too.

Comment: In political terms the questioner's determination who to serve is clearly intersectional between age and marital status. If you categorically refuse to serve black women, you can't successfully go to court claiming you aren't racist because you serve black men, and also that you aren't sexist because you serve white women. But it doesn't necessarily follow that all intersectional bias is so obviously identifed as that extreme example would be identified as *both* racist and sexist.

Comment: Can you add how this relates to the sexual orientation case linked in the question? I was at first fairly confused by this answer (and still am, somewhat), given that it doesn't refute this question saying discriminating based on marital status is legal, yet says discriminating based on sexual orientation is not legal (which doesn't appear to be consistent based on the quote in the other answer). But, based on the linked question, it seems the other case wasn't quite so clear-cut.

Comment: This answer doesn't address 1st Amendment concerns at all, which seem to be what this question is about. The existence of a law in Colorado does not say anything about whether that law is in violation of the 1st Amendment or not or whether or not some particular application of it would be such a violation. Lots of laws get limited or struck down in their entirety on the basis of violating one part or another of the federal constitution.

Answer (score 6):

In your hypothetical situation, I'm not aware of any law that prohibits denial of service merely because of age. (But as other answers show, marital status discrimination might and might not be relevant here. If there is martial status discrimination, then the discrimination would be illegal.)

Age for places of public accommodation is not a protected class under Colorado anti-discrimination law ([CO Rev Stat § 24-34-601 (2016)](https://law.justia.com/codes/colorado/2016/title-24/principal-departments/article-34/part-6/section-24-34-601)):

> (a) It is a discriminatory practice and unlawful for a person, directly or indirectly, to refuse, withhold from, or deny to an individual or a group, because of **disability, race, creed, color, sex, sexual orientation, marital status, national origin, or ancestry,** the full and equal enjoyment of the goods, services, facilities, privileges, advantages, or accommodations of a place of public accommodation or, directly or indirectly, to publish, circulate, issue, display, post, or mail any written, electronic, or printed communication, notice, or advertisement that indicates that the full and equal enjoyment of the goods, services, facilities, privileges, advantages, or accommodations of a place of public accommodation will be refused, withheld from, or denied an individual or that an individual's patronage or presence at a place of public accommodation is unwelcome, objectionable, unacceptable, or undesirable because of **disability, race, creed, color, sex, sexual orientation, marital status, national origin, or ancestry**.

Neither is age a protected class under the federal [Civil Rights Act Title II](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/2000a):

> (a) Equal access
>
> All persons shall be entitled to the full and equal enjoyment of the goods, services, facilities, privileges, advantages, and accommodations of any place of public accommodation, as defined in this section, without discrimination or segregation on the ground of **race, color, religion, or national origin**.

Comment: Careful with the argument. For example, if a young couple is allowed to get married at young age by their religion A, but would not allowed to get married at that age by another religion B, then we can very well argue that the refusal was due to religion, not due to age.

Comment: I could see this going either way. Marital status and religion could be theoretical hooks, but neither is obviously mandated in this case by the existing case law. A fact rich analysis would be required.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be clear, the initial linked Q&A does *not* show that bakers in certain US states can legally refuse service on the basis of sexual orientation, is concludes that federal law does not prohibit discrimination based on sexual orientation. Colorado law does.

So in Colorado, you would be open to a discrimination lawsuit, if you specifically refuse to make cakes for weddings involving one or more minors. You can refuse to make cakes for minors (age discrimination is not forbidden), but you cannot refuse to make cakes for minors getting married. Then you would have to appeal the ruling up to the Supreme Court. The basis for your appeal would be the Free Exercise Clause: government may not prohibit you from freely exercising your religious beliefs.

As demonstrated in [Masterpiece](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/584/16-111/), the legal proceeding against you by the government cannot evince
"clear and impermissible hostility toward [] sincere religious beliefs". That ruling is distinct from saying "must always roll over in the face of an alleged belief". The first paragraph of the holdings
allows that "religious and philosophical objections to gay marriage are protected views and in some instances protected forms of expression", and grant's that the artist's decisions about how to use his expressive skills "has a significant First Amendment speech component and implicates [] deep and sincere religious beliefs". But there was no specific holding that the Free Exercise Clause provides an escape from anti-discrimination laws.

There is no bright line yet drawn by SCOTUS on this topic. One thing that seems clear is that the courts will take a second look at compelled speech, and especially compelled speech that forces a person to repudiate their fundamental beliefs.

[Reynolds v. United States](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/98/145/), 98 U.S. 145 (polygamy is against the law) provides a limit on the Free Exercise Clause as an absolute: "A party's religious belief cannot be accepted as a justification for his committing an overt act, made criminal by the law of the land". The court there state that

> we think it may safely be said there never has been a time in any
>   State of the Union when polygamy has not been an offence against
>   society, cognizable by the civil courts and punishable with more or
>   less severity. In the face of all this evidence, it is impossible to
>   believe that the constitutional guaranty of religious freedom was
>   intended to prohibit legislation in respect to this most important
>   feature of social life. . . . Can a man excuse his practices to the
>   contrary because of his religious belief? To permit this would be to
>   make the professed doctrines of religious belief superior to the law
>   of the land, and in effect to permit every citizen to become a law
>   unto himself.

See also [Davis v. Beason](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/133/333/), 133 U.S. 333, for the same conclusion about the subordination of religious beliefs to the law of the land. However, the reasoning cited there:

> It was never intended that the first Article of Amendment to the
>   Constitution, that "Congress shall make no law respecting the
>   establishment of religion or prohibiting the free exercise thereof,"
>   should be a protection against legislation for the punishment of acts
>   inimical to the peace, good order and morals of society

probably would not fly in the current court (the question would be, what does the text say?).

Comment: WHAT?!? Are you saying that I can't go out and shoot John Doe, and then get off by pointing out that my religion **requires that I shoot John Doe**?!? Well, then I'll be danged if I'll be dropping that $5 in the collection plate on Sunday at the Holy Church Of St. We-Hate-John-Doe-Die-Ewe-Barstud-Die, Inc.!

Comment: Mostly ITA. But, while Colorado prohibits discrimination based on sexual orientation, it does not expressly prohibit discrimination against couples who marry under the age of 18 or 21, and it does have a statute providing that a private business may refuse service on any ground not expressly prohibited. The operative question under Colorado law would be whether discrimination against being married under age 21 would be a discrimination based upon marital status which doesn't have an obvious answer and is the subject of very little case law. I could see the case going either way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers and comments above, there is absolutely no consensus that this action is legal, or consensus that it is illegal. There is a majority for "this question is tricky".

If it ended up in court, then different judges or the same judge on different dates could rule different. Normally we also say "ask a lawyer" for tricky questions; for this one I wouldn't be surprised if a lawyer told you 'this depends on the judge" as well.

Comment: Fundamentally, court cases only happen in two circumstances: (a) one or both lawyers don't know what the outcome will be; (b) the clients overrule their lawyers, but not so outrageously that their lawyer has to refuse to represent them in a pointless case. (a) is pretty common even in cases without a jury. If the lawyers both know what the judge will rule, and the clients listen to the lawyers, you don't go to court.